# Looking for an example of a Validator inside a user control

Tags: asp.net, validation

Is it possible to have a validator inside of a User Control?  If so, does anyone have a snippet of code from a working example?

Comment: Will GridView or Repeater examples be of help to you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible.  There were some bugs on the containing ASPX page that were messing up the validator.